# Menu not stretching full length of div

Tags: css, html, menu

I have a menu that is not stretching all the way across my div tag like I need it to.  My div has a css class of menu and my div tag has a css class of nav.  I'm tried making the menu and the nav set to 100% width, but nothing is correcting the issue.  Please advise on what isn't correct.

Thanks in advance!

```
menu
{
/* padding: 4px 0px 4px;*/

 z-index:99999;
 width:  100%;

}

.nav
{
 width: 90%;
 margin: 20px auto 0px auto;

 }
```

Here's the HTML

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Site.Master.vb" Inherits="Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div class="nav">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                              <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                                  />
                              </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">


            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" 
                />

        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" IncludeStyleBlock="False">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Test" 
                        Target="New Window">
                          </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Test 2">

                    </asp:MenuItem>

                    </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">


    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">



</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u post  html or a link tto fiddle?

Comment: I updated the ticket with the html

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:auto;`. This will make your menu to stretch.

**For Instance,**

```
menu
{
/* padding: 4px 0px 4px;*/

 z-index:99999;
 width:  100%;
 overflow:auto;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I do this, it is placing a scrollbar on my menu instead of stretching it all the way across the div.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with fiddle so what tab/text do you want to see from this?

Comment: or provide a live link to see the issue. - @user2815584

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` (implied by your use of `z-index`), you can set left and right values to ensure the element stretches across the whole viewport:

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

This has the added advantage of letting you set padding on the menu without it affecting the overall width.